# Adding a minus sign symbol in PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Does anyone know how to add a minus sign symbol into a PowerPoint slide using VBA? I have been referencing this chart https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211643(v=office.11).aspx but don't see the minus symbol listed.

Answer (score 0):

The list you reference is for Office 2003. If that is what you're working with then those are the only AutoShape types available.

If you are working with a more recent version I suggest you look for the reference pages on MSDN for the version of Office that you are working with.

If you add a shape to a slide and select it you can always find the value of MsoAutoShapeType by querying it in the Immediate Window

```
?ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.AutoShapeType
```

Comment: Thank you Tim that was very helpful.

For anyone else who runs across the same problem, the value is 164 and the code is msoShapeMathMinus